# how to copy file from s3 bucket to ec2 home folder

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

how to copy file from s3 bucket to ec2 home folder.
ex: I have file in aws s3 bucket, i need to copy this file into ec2 instance home folder using java code.please help me thanks in advance.

Comment: See the docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjectUsingJava.html

Comment: What have you tried and what difficulty have you encountered? If this is a one-off requirement, you could instead use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 cp` command. Otherwise, see the Amazon S3 SDK for Java.